# Can't read xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I've the following `XML` saved into `settings.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Settings>
  <Type>15</Type>
  <Module>True</Module>
  <Capacity>10</Capacity>
</Settings>
```

I've created a class like this:

```
 public class Settings
 {
      public int Type { get; set; }
      public bool Module { get; set; }
      public int Capacity { get; set; }
 }
```

and this is my code that deserialize the `XML`:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("settings.config");
        var settings = doc.Root
                          .Elements("Settings")
                          .Select(x => new Settings
                          {
                              Type = (int)x.Attribute("Type"),
                              Module = (bool)x.Attribute("Module"),
                              Capacity = (int)x.Attribute("Capacity"),
                          })
                          .ToList();
```

The problem is that the `settings` variable return `Count = 0`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just remove `Root`; Settings *is* your root. Use this: `var settings = doc.Elements("Settings") ...`

Comment: @Quantic If I remove the `Root` I get `The value cannot be null. Value name: Attribute`. But I've no attribute in the xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues with your XML

1. `<Settings>` is your Root, it is not an element of your root.  If you want to have multiple `<Settings>`, then make a new root element, and put the `<Settings>` tags inside that.
2. `Type`, `Module`, and `Capacity` are Elements, not Attributes

---

If you only have 1 settings note, you can do something like the following:

```
var settignsNode = doc.Element("Settings");

var settings = new Settings()
{
    Type = (int)settignsNode.Element("Type"),
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Uhm so I need to createa Root node? Yep, for the bool is a typo error, fixed!

Comment: @IlDrugo Do you want to have multiple Settings nodes in your file?

Comment: Okay got it, thanks for the help. I really appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

Working example, but answer above is really explain what is going here

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><Settings><Type>15</Type><Module>True</Module><Capacity>10</Capacity></Settings>");
var settings = doc
                          .Elements("Settings")
                          .Select(x => new Settings
                          {
                              Type = (int.Parse(x.Elements("Type").First().Value)),
                              Module = bool.Parse(x.Elements("Module").First().Value),
                              Capacity = (int.Parse(x.Elements("Capacity").First().Value)),
                          })
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: `doc.Elements("Settings")` return null.

Comment: that way 'XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("settings.config");' not correctly load file

Comment: are you sure about this?

Comment: Test code in my answer, it work perfectly. But i use XDocument.Parse instead Load

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<Settings><Type>15</Type><Module>True</Module><Capacity>10</Capacity></Settings>");
var settings = doc
               .Elements("Settings")
               .Select(x => new Settings
               {
                   Type = (int)x.Element("Type"),
                   Module = (bool)x.Element("Module"),
                   Capacity = (int)x.Element("Capacity"),
                })
                .ToList();
```